# Help finding a passage from one of the Ender Wiggin books

Tags: enders-game, quotes

In one of the books in the Ender Wiggin series, a character is using a computer that is dynamically changing to accommodate his physical disabilities.  The passage describes in some detail how the interface adapts and how he grows more and more comfortable using it.

I'm pretty sure the character is Miro, but I could be wrong.

Can anyone locate this passage for me?  Is it available anywhere online?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're referring to the final chapter of [Speaker for the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_for_the_Dead), the sequel to Ender's Game.

> The terminal was learning to accommodate itself to him, too. Instead
> of long code sequences, he only had to begin a sequence and the
> machine would obey his instructions. Finally he did not even have to
> log on. He touched the keyboard and the terminal displayed a list of
> all the activities he usually engaged in, then scanned through them.
> He could touch a key and it would go directly to the activity he
> wanted, skipping dozens of preliminaries, saving him many painful
> minutes of typing one character at a time.
>
> At first he thought that Olhado had created the new program for him,
> or perhaps someone in the Mayor’s office. But Olhado only looked
> blankly at what the terminal was doing and said, “Bacâna,” that’s
> great. And when he sent a message to the Mayor, she never got it.
> Instead, the Speaker for the Dead came to visit him.
>
> “So your terminal is being helpful,” said Ender.

later

> "She [Jane] made a subtle, wonderful transition, and the woman on the screen was a lanky feline, sprawling sensuously on a tree limb. She purred noisily, stretched out a limb, groomed herself. “I can break your neck with a single blow from my paw,” she whispered; her tone of voice suggested seduction; her claws promised murder. “When I get you alone, I can bite your throat out with a single kiss.”
>
> **He [Miro] laughed. Then he realized that in all this conversation, he had actually forgotten how slurred his speech was. She understood every word. She never said, “What? I didn’t get that,” or any of the other polite but infuriating things that people said. She understood him without any special effort at all.**

Comment: This is a great passage but it's not the one I'm thinking of.  It was more like, "On the first day Miro struggled with the computer, but by the second week files would scroll through automatically and eventually the file he wanted would be already open when he got to the terminal."  This was before he knew who Jane was.

Comment: @Bobwise - See edit.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Comment: @Bobwise - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ). Don't forget to upvote and press the "accept" button if you found this useful.